# Simulate monitor device

Tags: screen, monitor, x11

I'm having an old PC running Ubuntu desktop edition, with no keyboard / mouse / screen - I'm accessing it only via ssh. I'd like to run X11 for using VNC - however - `startx` commands returns

```
Fatal server error:
no screens found
```

How do I simulate the screen in order to use VNC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 - Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/ubuntu-14-04-add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

Answer (score 2):

You can "forward" a GUI application to be displayed on your local machine while physically running on the remote server using `ssh -X`

```
ssh -X user@host
Password:

user@host# gedit
```

- this should open an editor window on your local machine.

See `man ssh` for more information.

Comment: I believe that will be a problem as I'm connecting from windows. I need to use VNC.